# Converting a vector of expressions into functions with the index being an input

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation, vector

I am trying to generate a list of functions from a vector of expressions. I have the list

$H=[1,x,x^2+1,3x^3+2x,4x^2+2x]$ and I want to define a function $f$ using two inputs such that
$f(n,x)$ returns the evaluation of the $n$th entry of $H$. For example, I want $f(3,y)=y^2+1$.

I tried this:

```
test[n_,y_]:=Module[
{func},
func[x_]:=Evaluate[Part[H,n]];
func[y]
].
```

However, it always return an expression of $x$ instead of the function output. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
ClearAll[x, f]
h = {1, x, x^2 + 1, 3*x^3 + 2*x, 4*x^2 + 2*x}
f[(n_Integer)?Positive,var_Symbol]:=(h[[n]]/.x->var)
```

And now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am sure there are other ways to do this.

Comment: Why are you restricting `var` to be a symbol?

Comment: @Roman well, from the spirit of the intended use, the var parameter is expected to be a symbol. But ofcourse one can change or remove this if that is not what they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
H = {1, x, x^2 + 1, 3*x^3 + 2*x, 4*x^2 + 2*x};
MapIndexed[(f[#2[[1]], x_] = #1) &, H];

f[3, y]
(*    1 + y^2    *)

?f
(*    f[1, x_] = 1
      f[2, x_] = x
      f[3, x_] = 1 + x^2
      f[4, x_] = 2 x + 3 x^3
      f[5, x_] = 2 x + 4 x^2     *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a bit new to the language so can you plese explain to me the meaning of the second line of your code? What does the & do and what are #2 and #1?

Comment: [Slots](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) refer to the arguments of a [pure function](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/pure-functions/). In this case, the pure function `(f[#2[[1]], x_] = #1) &` [sets](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) the value of the function `f` with given arguments, which afterwards we can check with `?f` as shown.